# Algorithm for testing angle equality

Tags: javascript, math, geometry, angle

My application has several circles rotated at arbitrary degrees and I need to test whether their rotations are equal (with respect to some error margin). A naive implementation goes like this:

```
function angleEquals(first, second, errorMargin) {
    return Math.abs(first - second) <= errorMargin;
}
```

But this fails since the rotations may grow to infinity. Thus we need to normalize both angles:

```
function normalizeAngle(angle) { 
    angle = angle % (2 * Math.PI); // normalize the angle to the interval [-2 * pi, 2 * pi]
    if (angle < 0)
        return 2 * Math.PI + angle; // normalize the angle to the interval [0, 2 * pi]
    return angle;
}
```

This works *almost* always but there are some corner cases that fail. For instance
`angleEquals(0, 2 * Math.PI - 1e-4, 1e-3)` is `false`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to normalize the difference between the angles, not the angles themselves.

```
diff = angle1-angle2 // calculate the difference
diff = diff % 2*PI // get it into the range [0, 2*PI)
if(diff > PI) diff -= 2*PI // get it into the range (-PI, PI]
diff = abs(diff) // get the absolute difference in the range [0,PI]
return (diff < errorMargin)
```

There's things you can do to tighten that up a bit, but it shows you the basic sequence of steps.

EDIT: For the sake of posterity, here's the tighter version.

```
diff = abs((abs(angle1-angle2) + PI) % (2*PI) - PI)
return (diff < errorMargin)
```

(That one doesn't rely on the behavior of modulus on negative numbers, and is less branchy.)

Comment: Doesn't `diff = diff % 2*PI` result in a range of `[-2PI, +2PI]` if *angle1* can be smaller than *angle2*? Also, if `angle1 = 0π` and `angle2 = 1.9π`, the angle between them is `0.1π` whereas the above will return `0.9π`.

Comment: Note that `diff % 2*PI` is equivalent to `(diff % 2) * PI` when you probably intended `diff % (2*PI)`.

Comment: @RobG I'm using the "normal" definition of modular arithmetic, where the result is always positive. That differs from C's standard modulus function, unfortunately. (I'm playing fast and loose with syntax above... `%` doesn't do anything for floats, of course.) You can cope with that by adding 2*PI and doing a second modulus.

Comment: The question is tagged "javascript", so if your answer isn't compliant then that should be pointed out in the answer (also in javascript `2.3 % 2 == 0.3` so the modulus operator does do **something** for floats).

Answer (score 1):

```
function angleEquals(first, second, errorMargin) {
    var diff = Math.abs(first - second) % (2 * Math.PI);
    return Math.min(diff, Math.abs(diff - 2 * Math.PI)) <= errorMargin;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When testing for rotation, I assume you always want to measure the shortest angle between the two, e.g. if one is rotated 0° and the other 359°, then the angle between them is 1°, not 359°.

The following function gets the smallest angle between the two and compares it to a tolerance:

```
function anglesInTolerance(angle1, angle2, tolerance) {

  // Radians in half a circle (180 deg) = 3.141592653589793
  var pi = Math.PI;

  // Get the difference in the angles
  var diff = Math.abs(angle1 - angle2)

  // Reduce to range +/- 2pi
  diff = diff % (2*pi);

  // If the difference is greater than pi (180 deg), subtract from 2pi
  if (diff > pi) diff = 2*pi - diff;

  return diff <= tolerance
}

var pi = Math.PI;
console.log(anglesInTolerance(0.0*pi, 1.9*pi, 0.1*pi)); // true
console.log(anglesInTolerance(0.5*pi, 0.4*pi, 0.1*pi)); // true
console.log(anglesInTolerance(0.4*pi, 0.5*pi, 0.1*pi)); // true
console.log(anglesInTolerance(0.1*pi, 1.9*pi, 0.1*pi)); // false
```

Note that to avoid rounding errors, you may want to round the numbers to say 3 or 4 decimal places which might be sufficient for your tolerance too, e.g. if you want to compare to ±0.0001 then round to 4 decimal places.

With rounding to 6 decimal places, the function can be:

```
// Values are in radians
function anglesInTolerance(angle1, angle2, tolerance) {
  var pi = Math.PI;
  var diff = Math.abs(angle1 - angle2) % (pi*2);

  if (diff > pi) diff = pi*2 - diff;
  return diff.toFixed(6) <= tolerance.toFixed(6);
}

console.log(anglesInTolerance(0.1*pi, 6.2*pi, 0.1*pi));   // true
console.log(anglesInTolerance(0.05*pi, 5.95*pi, 0.1*pi)); // true
```

Assuming that 6 decimal places is sufficient, a higher precision can be used if required.